# How to Pass a list of variables which are strings to stdout via subprocess.communicate

Tags: python, variables, subprocess, shlex

I can successfully hard code my values as follows below:
(my app launches and the parameters are passed and it runs as if I hit enter after manually entering in each parameter as I would if I ran it via command line, inputting the parameters manually and hitting enter after each one):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['C:\\Program Files\\app\\Bin\\current\\myapp.exe'], stdout=PIPE, 
stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='13 20180212.log 20180212.txt 
20180212fix.txt'.encode("utf-8"))[0]
stdout = p.communicate()[0]
print ("STDOUT:{}".format(stdout))`
```

But I want to replace these hard coded values with variables and it is not working successfully as follows:

Output prints as follows - and application is open but nothing is happening

C:\Program Files\app\Bin\current\myapp.exe
['13', '20180212.log', '20180212.txt', '20180212fix.txt']

```
option_num = "13"
date_log = "20180212.log"
date_text = "20180212.text"
date_fix = "20180212.fix"

arguments = [option_num, date_log, date_text, date_fix]
print (arguments)

command = [program_name]
command.extend(arguments)

output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print (output)
```

No error, the app just receives it all as one line of input instead of processing a return or enter after each variable - and if I look at the process open in Windows Process Explorer, it shows all the parameters being passed at once

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things going on around here. The bottom line of the behavior your describing is that `myapp.exe` which apparently receiving and processing inputs through `stdin`, but with that change you did not only switch to using variable, but also stopped passing them in through `stdin` and instead call your application with these values as positional argument.

If you indeed wanted to pass each value on a new line, you could do something like (depends on how you want to handle your grouping and what else you expect form the code). Variation on your code:

```
values = (option_num, date_log, date_text, date_fix)
input_data = '\n'.join(values)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input=input_data.encode('utf-8'))[0]
print("STDOUT:{}".format(stdout_data))
```

or (use `writelines` method over generator based off of `values`):

```
values = (option_num, date_log, date_text, date_fix)
p.stdin.writelines(((v+'\n').encode('utf-8') for v in values))
stdout_data = p.communicate()[0]
print("STDOUT:{}".format(stdout_data))
```

or (similar to above, using `write` of `stdin` file-like object created for `PIPE`):

```
values = (option_num, date_log, date_text, date_fix)
for v in values:
    input_line = (v+'\n').encode('utf-8')  # append newline and convert to bytes
    p.stdin.write(input_line)
stdout_data = p.communicate()[0]
print("STDOUT:{}".format(stdout_data))
```

But, that is the other thing I wanted to mention, that is not what the initial example did. The values were passed space (and not newline) delimited. So it that work, the receiving `myapp.exe` might actually expect spaces and not newlines (or any whitespace character in which case both were OK).

Comment: Thank you I will try that as well, I figured it out right after posting, all I had to to was add a space after the variable. It is a very old legacy written in C++ and expects keyboard input after each variable is passed. the space works as an enter.